# Masked input field in Trinidad

Tags: javascript, jsf, trinidad

PrimeFaces has a `<p:inputMask>` component which forces an input to fit in a defined mask as input is being typed.

For example:

```
<h:outputText value="Date: " />
<p:inputMask value="#{maskController.date}" mask="99/99/9999"/>
```

Is there any equivalent in Trinidad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding javascript support with JQuery - masked input plugin :
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
<tr:inputDate id="idDate" value="04/10/2013"
       autoSubmit="true"
       label="Label: ">
    <tr:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
</tr:inputDate>
```

See also: [Trinidad Tag-Documentaion](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc.html)

Comment: Thanks , but what if I need numeric fields or text fields ?

Comment: They have a <tr:convertNumber> component for that. Read converters and validators on the page I gave you the link: Trinidad Tag-Documentaion

Comment: thanks but it's not what I wanted.. what I need some masked input on a TEXT field with pattern like - ***-***-** , I won't be able to do that with trinidad. where as in primeFaces I will..